# How to get moving combination from two List<String> in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm having two `List<String>` which contains

```
ListOne
          A
          B
          C
ListTwo
          A
          B
          C
          D
```

Now i need to get the moving combinations to a list string

So the output list will contain

```
         A-B
         A-C
         A-D
         B-C
         B-D
         C-D
```

Now i'm using `Nested for loop` for this.?
Is there any way to do this using `LINQ` or `LAMBDA EXPRESSION`
Please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance

**Sample Code**

```
List<String> ListOne = new List<string> { "A","B","C"};
List<String> ListTwo = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

List<String> Result = new List<string>(from X in ListOne 
                                       from Y in ListTwo 
                                       where X!=Y
                                        select string.Format("{0}-{1}", X, Y));
```

But its not giving the correct output

```
  It produces like

            A-B
            A-C
            A-D
            B-A
            B-C
            B-D
            C-A
            C-B
            C-D
```

But the required output is like

```
         A-B
         A-C
         A-D
         B-C
         B-D
         C-D
```

**Sample Code using `For Loop`**

```
List<String> ResultTwo = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ListOne.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ListTwo.Count; j++)
            {
                if(ListOne[i] != ListTwo[j])
                    if (ResultTwo.Contains(ListOne[i] + "-" + ListTwo[j]) == false && ResultTwo.Contains(ListTwo[j] + "-" + ListOne[i]) == false) 
                ResultTwo.Add(ListOne[i] + "-" + ListTwo[j]);
            }
        }
```

its working fine.... but i just need a simple way ( Using `LINQ`)

Comment: Do you mean to pair the elements of the two lists such that each element in list one is only paired with elements of list two that come after the occurrence of the element in list one? Maybe you could post your current code, if its not too big.

Comment: @rmx : Edited in.............

Comment: You should explain what do you really want. It's not really clear from your question. Which of the pairs do you want to get in the output, and which you don't want? Is the choice made on the values or on the positions in the lists? For example, what should be the output for list1=D,C,B,A; list2=A,B,C,D? What should be the output for list1=A,B,C; list2=B,B,D,B?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following your edits this should do the trick:

```
List<string> ListOne = new List<string>(){"A","B","C"};
List<string> ListTwo = new List<string>(){ "A","B","C","D"};

var result = from a in ListOne
             from b in ListTwo
             let condition = a.CompareTo(b)
             where condition != 0
             select condition < 0 ? a + "-" + b : b + "-" + a;


foreach (var v in result.Distinct())
{
    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

The second version that preserves order (ItemFromList1 - ItemFromList2):

```
        var result =
            from o in
                (
                    from a in ListOne
                    from b in ListTwo
                    let condition = a.CompareTo(b)
                    where condition != 0
                    select new { a, b, condition }
                )
                group o by
                    o.condition < 0 ? o.a + "-" + o.b : o.b + "-" + o.a into g
                select g.Select(n => n.a + "-" + n.b).Take(1).ToArray()[0];
```

Comment: @Daniel -- now THIS is an answer. +1!

Comment: Its gives only `A-B` . But the expected output is `A-B` ,`C-A`,`C-B`

Comment: @Pramodh, how do you get to that logic?

Comment: @astander : Please see my Second edit(Sample code using `For Loop`)

Comment: @Euphoric I think your downvote is not justified as the original question and concept was edited 3 times and I didn't track all the changes.

Comment: @Andrzej Nosal: Ok, seems like you kept up.

Answer (score 2):

So you want all matches except

- item matched to itself
- item matched to smaller item

and no duplicates.

Here it is:

```
IEnumerable<string> result = 
  (
    from a in ListOne
    from b in ListTwo
    where a != b
    select a.CompareTo(b) < 0 ? a + "-" + b : b + "-" + a
  ).Distinct();
```

Stating the requirement is 90% of the battle.

---

If you NEED the first item in the pairing to come from the first list, this will do it:

```
IEnumerable<string> result = 
  (
    from a in ListOne
    from b in ListTwo
    select new
    {
      A = a,
      B = b,
      Combo = a.CompareTo(b) < 0 ? a + "-" + b : b + "-" + a
    } into x
    group x by x.Combo into g
    select g.Select(x2 => x2.A + "-" + x2.B).First()
  )
```

Comment: the second one is showing some error like ` Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' `

Answer (score 2):

```
var listA = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
var listB = new List<string> { "A", "B" };
var result = listA.SelectMany((a, indexA) =>
                     listB.Where((b, indexB) => 
                            listB.Contains(a) ? !b.Equals(a)&&indexB > indexA 
                                              : !b.Equals(a))
                          .Select(b => string.Format("{0}-{1}", a, b)));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the logic of validating is added to the list

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> a = new List<string>() { "C", "D", "L" };
        List<string> b = new List<string>() { "C", "L", "C", "D" };

        var pairValuesNotEqual = from vara in a
                from varb in b
                where vara != varb
                select new Pair(vara, varb);


        Set sets = new Set();
        sets.AddRange(pairValuesNotEqual);

        foreach (var item in sets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.First + " - " + item.Second);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Set : List<Pair>
{
    public new void AddRange(IEnumerable<Pair> pairs)
    {
        foreach (var item in pairs)
        {
            this.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public new void Add(Pair item)
    {
        if (!IsExists(item))
            base.Add(item);
    }

    private bool IsExists(Pair item)
    {
        foreach (Pair i in this)
        {
            if (i.First == item.Second && i.Second == item.First)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think LINQ is good enough for this, I got this, but it is not good looking :

```
        var A = from one in ListOne
                from two in ListTwo
                where one != two
                let x = one.CompareTo(two) < 0 ? one : two
                let y = one.CompareTo(two) < 0 ? two : one
                select new { X = x, Y = y};

        var B = A.Distinct().Select(a => a.X + "-" + a.Y);
```

Acualy, when I clean up your nested foreach code a little bit, I like it more than LINQ:

```
        List<string> outList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string s1 in ListOne)
        {
            foreach (string s2 in ListTwo)
            {
                if (s1 != s2 &&
                    !outList.Contains(s1 + "-" + s2) &&
                    !outList.Contains(s2 + "-" + s1))
                {
                    outList.Add(s1 + "-" + s2);
                }
            }
        }
```