# C# : How to get running combination from two List<String> based on a master list

Tags: c#, linq

Dear all , this is something like my previous  question [How to get moving combination from two List<String> in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470447/how-to-get-moving-combination-from-two-liststring-in-c/4470714#4470714)

I'm having a masterlist and two childlist like below

```
        List<String> MasterList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
        List<String> ListOne = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
        List<String> ListTwo = new List<String> { "B", "D" };
```

I just need to get the running combination from the above list for that i'm using like(previous question's answer(Thanks Danny Chen))

```
        List<String> Result = new List<string>();
        Result = ListOne.SelectMany((a, indexA) => ListTwo
                                    .Where((b, indexB) => ListTwo
                                    .Contains(a) ? !b.Equals(a) && indexB > indexA : 
                                    !b.Equals(a)).Select(b => string.Format("{0}-{1}", a, b))).ToList();
```

so the Result list will contain

```
        "A-B"
        "A-D"
        "B-D"
        "C-B"
        "C-D"
```

Now my problem is the sorting issue

In the above result the fourth entry is `C-B` but it should be `B-C`. Because in the `MasterList` the `C` is after `B`.

How to do this in my existing `linq` .

Please help me to do this.

Comment: I haven't understood the why of MasterList. And also, shouldn't the output have to be: "A-B, A-D, B-D, C-D"?

Comment: @ AS-CII : Friend,  In the `ResultList` the item should be in the `MasterList` order. i.e,  the itsm should start in the master list order

Comment: The above code doesn't produce "B-D".

Comment: You wrote: "How to do this in my existing linq", and I answered with your request, and you writing other approach is what you want, I think you should think what you want then ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really clear on the exact requirement here, so does the MasterList dictate which of the two items should appear first? What about the order of the X1-X2 list? i.e. should B-C appear before B-D because C appears before D in the MasterList?

Anyway, here's something that produces the result you've asked for so far:

```
List<String> MasterList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
List<String> ListOne = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
List<String> ListTwo = new List<String> { "B", "D" };

ListOne.SelectMany(i => 
ListTwo.Where(i2 => i != i2)
       .Select(i2 => 
            {
                if (MasterList.IndexOf(i) < MasterList.IndexOf(i2))
                    return string.Format("{0}-{1}", i, i2);
                else
                    return string.Format("{0}-{1}", i2, i);
            }
       ));
```

outputs:

```
A-B
A-D
B-D
B-C
C-D
```